Creating new variable under dplyr based on similar values in many columns
I have a dataset where multiple individuals attended 6 events. Dataset looks somewhat as follows:
Series  event_1    event_2  event_3  event_4  event_5  event_6
  1      Bill       Alicia   Alicia   Bill     Denise   Bill
  2      Will       Stormy    Bill    Dob       June    Denise
  3      Stormy      Dave     Sally   Denise    Alicia   April

I want to create a new variable based on which of these participants attended many events no matter which series. So for instant Bill attended 4 times and Alicia attended three times and Denise attended 3 times as well. So there were at least 2 participants who attended 3 events and one participant who attended 4 times.
Could you help me with the best way of go about this?
Thanks

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

pivot_longer(df, -Series) |>
  count(value) |> 
  arrange(-n)


 1 Bill       4
 2 Alicia     3
 3 Denise     3
 4 Stormy     2
 5 April      1
 6 Dave       1
 7 Dob        1
 8 June       1
 9 Sally      1
10 Will       1


df <- structure(list(Series = c(1, 2, 3), event_1 = c("Bill", "Will", 
"Stormy"), event_2 = c("Alicia", "Stormy", "Dave"), event_3 = c("Alicia", 
"Bill", "Sally"), event_4 = c("Bill", "Dob", "Denise"), event_5 = c("Denise", 
"June", "Alicia"), event_6 = c("Bill", "Denise", "April")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))


You can use count(sort = TRUE) and avoid the call to arrange().

@lotus That's true! Similarly, adding arrange(-n) avoids the need to add "sort=TRUE", which tells tally to call arange anyway. :P Also, readers of the code may not know that sorting is done in descending order. How to sort in ascending order without calling arrange?

df <- data.frame(
  Series = c(1, 2, 3),
  event_1 = c("Bill", "Will", "Stormy"),
  event_2 = c("Alicia", "Stormy", "Dave"),
  event_3 = c("Alicia", "Bill", "Sally"),
  event_4 = c("Bill", "Dob", "Denise"),
  event_5 = c("Denise", "June", "Alicia"),
  event_6 = c("Bill", "Denise", "April")
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("event_"),values_to = "participant") %>% 
  count(participant)


# A tibble: 10 × 2
   participant     n
   <chr>       <int>
 1 Alicia          3
 2 April           1
 3 Bill            4
 4 Dave            1
 5 Denise          3
 6 Dob             1
 7 June            1
 8 Sally           1
 9 Stormy          2
10 Will            1


In base R you can do
as.data.frame(table(unlist(df[, -1])))

     Var1 Freq
1  Alicia    3
2   April    1
3    Bill    4
4    Dave    1
5  Denise    3
6     Dob    1
7    June    1
8   Sally    1
9  Stormy    2
10   Will    1


As per the update from the comment, you can try
transform(
    aggregate(
        Series ~ event,
        reshape(
            df,
            direction = "long",
            idvar = "Series",
            v.names = "event",
            varying = -1
        ), sort
    ),
    n = lengths(Series),
    CrossSeries = lengths(lapply(Series, unique))
)

which gives
    event     Series n CrossSeries
1  Alicia    1, 1, 3 3           2
2   April          3 1           1
3    Bill 1, 1, 1, 2 4           2
4    Dave          3 1           1
5  Denise    1, 2, 3 3           3
6     Dob          2 1           1
7    June          2 1           1
8   Sally          3 1           1
9  Stormy       2, 3 2           2
10   Will          2 1           1


Try this
> rev(stack(sort(table(unlist(df[-1])), T)))
      ind values
1    Bill      4
2  Alicia      3
3  Denise      3
4  Stormy      2
5   April      1
6    Dave      1
7     Dob      1
8    June      1
9   Sally      1
10   Will      1


Thanks everyone what if I want just across series and not within any givens series?

@MaleehaShahid what do you mean?

I meant that Bill attended total of 4 times but across series he only attended 2 series . I guess I will have to create a binary variable (If present at least in one column assign ‘1’ other wise assign ‘0’.

@MaleehaShahid see my update

I work with pivot_longer alot. Thank you for all your responses.
